# Python pandas apply function to grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on Titanic dataset
One ticket can be issued for several passengers, i. e. several passengers may have same ticket number
The 'Fare' feature for all those passengers will be the same and equal to the whole ticket fare
For example if there are 4 passengers travelling by one ticket, the ticket fare can be 40$, but each passenger fare should be $10.
So one should divide ticket fare by ticket frequency to calculate fare per passenger.
But there is one more thing: babies are charged  $2 and children younger 12 are charged half adult fare.
So I am trying to calculate price payed by each adult in the ticket taking into account children fares.
Here is a sample data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [0.5,5,20,21,22,23,24], 'Fare': [17,17,17,40,40,40,40], 'TicketNum': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]})
```

```
       Age      Fare    TicketNum

0      0.5       17         1

1      5.0       17         1

2      20.0      17         1

3      21.0      40         2

4      22.0      40         2

5      23.0      40         2

6      24.0      40         2
```

first I make this function:

```
def fare_calc(x):
    ticket_fare = x['Fare'].mean()

    group_size = x.shape[0]
    babies_count = x[x['Age']<1].count()
    child_count = x[x['Age']<12].count()
    adult_count = group_size - babies_count - child_count
    adult_fare = (ticket_fare - babies_count * 2) / (adult_count + child_count*0.5)
    return adult_fare
```

then I try:

```
df['TicketFreq'] = df.groupby('TicketNum')['TicketNum'].transform('count')
df['Fare2'] = df[df.TicketFreq>1].groupby(['TicketNum'])['Age','Fare'].agg(fare_calc)
```

and get an error:
 
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

desired output is the following:

```
       Age      Fare    TicketNum    Fare2

0      0.5       17         1           10

1      5.0       17         1           10

2      20.0      17         1           10

3      21.0      40         2           10

4      22.0      40         2           10

5      23.0      40         2           10

6      24.0      40         2           10
```

Comment: your function accepts only one argument, but when you are calling the function you are passing two arguments Age and Fare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

I create columnwise series of values using the `pd.Series()` and `.repeat()` functions.

By the way, You forgot to exclude babies_count from child_count using `(df['Age']<12) & (df['Age']>1)`

```
def fare_calc(x):
    group_size   = x.shape[0]
    ticket_fare  = pd.Series(x['Fare'].mean().repeat(group_size))
    babies_count = x[x['Age']<1 ]['Age'].count()
    child_count  = x[(df['Age']<12) & (df['Age']>1)]['Age'].count()
    adult_count  = group_size - babies_count - child_count
    adult_fare   = (ticket_fare - babies_count * 2) / (adult_count + child_count * 0.5)
    return adult_fare
```

And finally extract solely values of the stacked Series created by the `apply` function using the `.values` to prevent from "incompatible index" TypeError.

```
df['Fare2'] = df[df.TicketFreq>1].groupby(['TicketNum']).apply(fare_calc).values

print(df)
    Age  Fare  TicketNum  TicketFreq  Fare2
0   0.5    17          1           3   10.0
1   5.0    17          1           3   10.0
2  20.0    17          1           3   10.0
3  21.0    40          2           4   10.0
4  22.0    40          2           4   10.0
5  23.0    40          2           4   10.0
6  24.0    40          2           4   10.0
```

EDIT 1: more intuitive version of the previous function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [0.5,5,20,21,22,23,24], 'Fare': [17,17,17,40,40,40,40], 'TicketNum': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]})
df['TicketFreq'] = df.groupby('TicketNum')['TicketNum'].transform('count')

def fare_calc(x):
    group_size       = x.shape[0]
    x['ticket_fare'] = x['Fare'].mean()
    babies_count     = x[x['Age']<1 ]['Age'].count()
    child_count      = x[(df['Age']<12) & (df['Age']>1)]['Age'].count()
    adult_count      = group_size - babies_count - child_count
    x['adult_fare']  = (x['ticket_fare'] - babies_count * 2) / (adult_count + child_count * 0.5)
    return x['adult_fare']

df['Fare2'] = df[df.TicketFreq>1].groupby(['TicketNum']).apply(fare_calc).values

print(df)
    Age  Fare  TicketNum  TicketFreq  Fare2
0   0.5    17          1           3   10.0
1   5.0    17          1           3   10.0
2  20.0    17          1           3   10.0
3  21.0    40          2           4   10.0
4  22.0    40          2           4   10.0
5  23.0    40          2           4   10.0
6  24.0    40          2           4   10.0
```

EDIT 2: even simpler where 'Fare2' is directly created inside the function

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [0.5,5,20,21,22,23,24], 'Fare': [17,17,17,40,40,40,40], 'TicketNum': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]})
df['TicketFreq'] = df.groupby('TicketNum')['TicketNum'].transform('count')

def fare_calc(x):
    group_size       = x.shape[0]
    ticket_fare      = x['Fare'].mean()
    babies_count     = x[x['Age']<1 ]['Age'].count()
    child_count      = x[(df['Age']<12) & (df['Age']>1)]['Age'].count()
    adult_count      = group_size - babies_count - child_count
    x['Fare2']       = (ticket_fare - babies_count * 2) / (adult_count + child_count * 0.5)
    return x

df = df[df.TicketFreq>1].groupby(['TicketNum']).apply(fare_calc)

print(df)
    Age  Fare  TicketNum  TicketFreq  Fare2
0   0.5    17          1           3   10.0
1   5.0    17          1           3   10.0
2  20.0    17          1           3   10.0
3  21.0    40          2           4   10.0
4  22.0    40          2           4   10.0
5  23.0    40          2           4   10.0
6  24.0    40          2           4   10.0
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get an error: 'float' object has no attribute 'repeat'. Honestly, I don't understand, why do we need repeat here.

Comment: I repeated mean values so that every later calcul (i.e. adult_fare) was also repeated on every rows of the subgroup. Anyway, i edited a new version of the function easier to understand. By the way the float issue you mentionned is weired because x['Fare'].mean() type is a numpy.float not a simple float, so repeat should have worked ;-)

Comment: Wow, that worked, thanks! Looks like witchcraft to me. If I insert print(x) into the function fare_calc(x), then x is printed 3 times. Group with ticket num 1 gets printed 2 times which I don't understand. I understand that you changed the function so that it returns pd.Series, but what is the role of adding .values to append? You said it is to  extract solely values of the stacked Series created by the apply function. What does this mean? Maybe you could point somewhere to read? Thanks again!

Comment: Each subgroup df created by .groupby is processed seperatly in the apply. Therefore, fare_calc function is used as many times as there are groups (i.e 2 times). At the end, every output is pilled up columnwise. Returning only the 'adult_fare' column required to only take values because of index issues. See EDIT2, simpler version and more related to yours where 'Fare2' column is directly created inside fare_calc and where the whole dataframe (e.g. x) is now returned so we don't need to fix any index issues with .values. Thx to put the green check if that solved your issue ;-)

Comment: It did! Thanks a lot for help and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Hey your formular seems to be wrong however the `fare_calc` function gets exectued when u replace the `.agg` call by `.apply` and remove the two columns you specified. See example below

```
df[df.TicketFreq>1].groupby(['TicketNum']).apply(fare_calc)
```

Further there were just a few changes necessary for your function. 
To get numeric numvers for the babie_count and child_count you need to specify a colum to get only one integer

```
def fare_calc(x):
    ticket_fare = x['Fare'].mean()
    group_size = x.shape[0]
    babies_count = x[x['Age']<1]['Age'].count()
    child_count = x[x['Age']<12]['Age'].count()
    adult_count = group_size - babies_count - child_count
    adult_fare = (ticket_fare - babies_count * 2) / (adult_count + child_count * 0.5)
    return adult_fare
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However the output is strange. Almost all bins in Fare2 column are NaN except for two, which are 10 and 15.

Answer (score 0):

A minor but immediate problem is that in your last line of code, `['Age', 'Fare']` should be `[['Age', 'Fare']]`, as you want to index with a list of column names.

The main issue is that you have written `fare_calc()` to work on the whole DataFrame, but the function that is passed to `df.agg()` will be applied to each column individually.